# Jquery pass array in set interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var slides= ["<?php echo $slider[0]; ?>", "<?php echo $slider[1]; ?>", "<?php echo $slider[2]; ?>"]; 
    var firstSlide = [1, 2, 0];
    var lastSlide = [2, 0, 1];
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    function degistir(){

        $("#leftslide").attr("src", "admin/slider/"+slides[firstSlide[i]]); 
        $("#rightslide").attr("src", "admin/slider/"+slides[lastSlide[j]]);
        i += 1;
        j += 1;
        if(i == 2) i = 0;
        if(j == 2) j = 0;

    }
    setInterval('degistir()',5500);
});
</script>
```

"degistir" function does not work in `$(function(){})` but when i carry it to another `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` , i couldn't pass the array to another script. So what should i do?

Comment: setInterval(degistir,5500);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have improper syntax for your `setInterval`. It should be:

```
setInterval(degistir, 5500);
```

See the [`setInterval` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).